# How can I do this SQL with Query Builder Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I'm confused how to do SQL below in Query Builder.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM (
    SELECT
        i.ID
        ,l.NOMELOJA
        , CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATALOG, 103) AS DATA
        , DATEPART(HOUR,DATALOG) AS HORA
        , CASE WHEN LOGINTEGRACAO = 'LOJA CONSULTADA COM SUCESSO' THEN 'OK' ELSE 'NOK' END AS STATUS
    FROM DMN_INTEGRACAO_LOG i, DMN_LOJAS_LINKED_SERVER l
    WHERE TABELA='DMN_LOJAS_ORDERS'
    AND DATALOG >= (SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 112))
    AND i.ID = l.ID
    ) A
WHERE STATUS = 'NOK'
GROUP BY ID
    , NOMELOJA
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATA, 103)
    , HORA
    , STATUS
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

Comment: [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) can you find all reference about that.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].

Comment: Let's see what you've done so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: As a first step you should optimize your original query. The nested table for example does not seem necessary. In addtion you're using cross joins and filtering on the where which is also not recommended. Once you've refactored the query it would be trivial to convert it to Laravel's query builder if you just look up what you need in the manual

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries).

When I need complex queries as this one I like to use RAW joining. At its base, your query is a more complicated version of the following one

```
Model::where('status', 'NOK')
->leftJoin(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM A /*use raw query */'))
->groupBy('ID')
->orderBy('1')
->get()
```

Comment: Thanks clod968 i'll try that.